# Rails route globbing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I create the Rails route that would match this with the parameter 2019, 2018, 2017 passed into the controller?

```
/blog-page-2019

/blog-page-2018

/blog-page-2017

...
```

Comment: Is the "2019, 2018, 2017" portion part of a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parameterize the whole 'blog-page-{year}' path, for example for GET request:

```
get ":blog_path", to: "blog#page" , constraints: { blog_path: /blog-page-\d{4}/ }
```

And in your controller, extract the year (I assumed you want this)

```
def page
  year = params[:blog_path][-4..-1]
end
```